# Pass variables to another module which contains classes

Tags: python, import

I have a module with a Class

```
class Record(object): 
    Name = ''
    Gender = '' 
    Age = '' 

Line = 'Bob=Male=40'
M = Line.split('=')   

exec(M[0] + ' = ' + 'Record()')
exec(M[0] + '.' + 'Name'   + ' = ' + "'" + M[0] + "'")
exec(M[0] + '.' + 'Gender' + ' = ' + "'" + M[1] + "'")
exec(M[0] + '.' + 'Age'    + ' = ' + "'" + M[2] + "'")
```

I am trying to import the above module but to pass it the "Line" variable.
How could I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this one line should do the job

```
# in main script

from lib import file_name
file_name.Line = Line #Assuming line is declared already
```

you need not declare Line in your module

Comment: Where  is lib declared?

Comment: @user1530405 lib is your package. Just replace lib with your package name if you have one or directly import your module.

Answer (score 0):

You create objects by calling a class. You don't need to use exec to do that

```py
#record.py

class Record:
    def __init__(self, name, gender, age):
        self.Name = name
        self.Gender = gender 
        self.Age = age
    
    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join((self.Name, self.Gender, self.Age))


Person = Record("Bob", "Male", "30")
```

```py
# workspace.py
import record

print(record.Person)

Person2 = record.Record("Alice", "F", "30")
print(Person2)
```

Outputs:

```
Bob M 30
Alice F 30
```

In python you probably would get away with this

```py
name = "Bob"
gend = "M"
age = '30'

exec(f'{name} = record.Record("{name}", "{gend}", "{age}")')
print(Bob)
# Bob M 30
```

But I would not advise that

Comment: I would like to reference the record by it's name Ie: Bob.Male or Bob.Age